# How to duplicate swipe gallery

Tags: adobe-flash

New to Adobe Flash. With the default Swipe template. I have made 2 scene just with the color variation change. I have just duplicate the scene and change the colours in the scene 2 also. So i have now scene 1 and scene 2. With the [reference video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6BfQOJgn8YI) i made the 1st scene and just duplicate same scene and change the colors and rename to scene 2. When i press ctrl+enter i get this error.

[image]

Before making the scene 2 i did not get the error. But after duplicate the scene 1 and color change i get this error. May i know what changes i have to make to get rid of this error to get a swipe animation. Any suggestion or help.

[sample File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RUEWP7_dWCMMGi7uBt3NnBpW0KpK6JXD)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just rename all the var (currentGalleryItem, totalGalleryItems, slideCounter, slideLeft, moveGalleryLefta, etc. )

or i have rename all the var [download](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YNF-jgCZrB5Ee_P8TgQ96bGCBqG4WFd7) and just copy paste.